# Zend Studio issue adding Zend Server - Windows 10

Tags: zend-studio

I am trying to add Zend Server to a new installation of Zend Studio.  As soon as i click add server i get the following error:

An internal error occurred during: "Adding local Zend Server".
For input string: "2,018"

Does anyone know how to fix this or a work around?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add Zend Server 2018 to Zend Studio as a PHP Server, follow the below steps:

1. Go to Zend Studio | Window | Preferences | PHP | Servers | New | Remote Zend Server
2. Provide all the required details and click on Finish.

In this way, Zend Studio is not giving any error message and able to add Zend Server.

For Reference: http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/adding_a_remote_zend_server.htm